# slideToggle the whole div

Tags: javascript, css, slidetoggle

I am developing a page where the content is hidden behind a jquery toggle button. I want the content wrapper to expand both horizontally and vertically when clicked (currently the wrapper only expands vertically).

I'm not sure how to organize my files. Currently, the wrapper has these css attributes:

```
#wrapper {
width: 900px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 40px;
background-color:#FFF;
border-radius: 42px;
-moz-border-radius:42px;
padding:30px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}
```

The "panel" div controls the javascript via:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

$(".btn-slide").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
}); 
    });
</script>
```

Changing the #wrapper width directly in the css causes the content inside the slideToggle to be truncated: ie. the wrapper won't expand to the proper horizontal size after sliding if the width is set. On the other hand, if I remove the width attribute, the page is no longer properly wrapped. How should I remedy this problem?

```
<div id="wrapper" >
<div id="intro" class="content-wrapper"><a href="#" class="btn-slide"><span class="content">CONTENT</span></a>
    <div class="wrapper-inner container"><div class="home-page container">
        <div id="panel">
```

Comment: Can you use some fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Kyle, I added the relevant html. Sylvio, I haven't been able to find the answer with fiddle, sadly. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure i fully understand the problem, but here are 2 possible solutions:
1. use the jQuery .animate() method instead of slideToggle, that will give you all the flexibility you need.
2. if you are having problems with the surrounding layout, place your wrapper inside a div with a fixed size, and change your #wrapper to position:absolute

Comment: Thanks karnyj. I'm using animate now, but am having problems getting the width to expand on click. The width of my wrapper is 300px, but I want it to expand to 900px on click. The jquery handle is set to panel, which animates to 'toggle' the height. How can I get the wrapper width to expand when panel expands on the button click?  Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks animate(); was the answer